# Send a Post with url parameter with Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want to send a POST with Retrofit 2. The url has some parameters:

```
 @Headers({
      "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;",
      "User-Agent: my-app"
 })
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("server/directory/location.type")
`public Call<POJOStringValue> dataWithUr(@Path("arg1") String arg1, @Path("arg2"), String arg2);
```

The url looks like this

> www.website.com/server/directory/location.type?arg1=value1&arg2=value2

I was requested to use a POST request. The values (value1 and value2) are dynamic at runtime. I started the project with Xamarin using HttpClient and now I'm rewriting it in Java native. In C# all I had to do was to concact the strings and send the resulting string in a single Post.

I tried to use @Path and the error was :

> "server/directory/location.type" does not contain "{arg1}". (parameter #1)

Then, I tried to use @Query and the error was:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Finally I tried with @Field the request never gets any response (I sette the connection timeout to 5 seconds)

Please help me, or tell me if I have to don't have any other choice but to use a GET request.

**((EDIT))**
Here is my code for the setup of the client:

```
private static void setupClient(){
    final OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .build();


    //define retrofit
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(iXUtils.getUrl_())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    this.client_ = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
}
```

The get() method:

```
public static RequestInterface get(){
    return this.client_;
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
 public String callFunctionDB(String arg1,  String arg2){
    setupClient();

    Call<POJOStringValue> call  = get().dataWithUrlString(arg1, arg2);
    try {
        POJOStringValue response = call.execute().body();
        String value = response.getValue();
        int test = 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String value = "it failded";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "test";
}
```

I put the test=0 to be able to put a breaking point, it never gets there. Plus I called the method "callFunctionDB" in a doInbackground to avoid the  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: share your code for calling web service

Comment: `@FormUrlEncoded` why?

Comment: you were right that was one of the problems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Retrofit requires you to have at least one form parameter if you request form encoding.  You have answered your own question -- you are using query parameters instead of POST fields, so that annotation is not necessary.  Remove the `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation, and change your parameters to `@Query` annotations.